# Magento doesn't load my CSS

Tags: css, magento

I have change a bit of code in my CSS from Magento for my header logo but Magento doesn't load my new CSS update and still shows the old one.

I have already refresh the cache in Magento

Flush Magento Cache

Flush Cache storage

Flush Javascript/CSS Cache

At System - Cache Management

I have a folder var/cache and in here folders like mage--0, mage--1
i have tried to back-up them so i can restore it when i delete them and something won't wrong but i cant back-up it.

Answer (score 1):

Hello first of all you can always safely delete the contents of var/cache you do not need to back it up. I konw it might sound silly but did you clear browser cache? Also make shure you changed the correct css file, use Firebug to see if your changes are not overwritten by other rules. A link to the project and more information will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the browser is caching your files, not the server. To check, try either merging your files or unmerging your files and refresh the page. If you see the changes, then it is indeed your browser that is caching the files.

In that case, we've developed a handy little extension that automatically refreshes the merged JS + CSS static files. http://extensions.activo.com/css-and-javascript-versioning.html

Answer (score 0):

you may be using different theme. check in system config design section what package and theme you are using and then check for that folder in skin and change. delete the var cache and changes will show. you do not need to back up var cache

Answer (score 0):

Its also important to check **System -> Design**, where design overrides are located. Recently we've had a problem with this, someone (we are not sure who, hacker?) added override without dates, and whole shop become broken (we have pretty sophisticated package with lots of modifications). It took us about 30 minutes to figure out what was going on.